# iterate through few UL lists looking for class in each. if not found throw error and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, iteration

Sorry if title confuses. Hard to think of how to describe the problem in few words.

I have 3 different lists containing "level", "category", "time" for the game. Originally none of the lists' items have any class. When selected an item from each list, it gets a class 'activeSelection'.

I need to check if in each of the lists there is an item that has that class. If not, then show the warning under the list (there is a warning for each list) that at the moment is hidden. Also not let "startGame()" function to execute.

I need it to work so if 2 lists are missing that class, the warning would be shown under both of those lists. The same if all 3 lists are missing the class.

```js
const levelList = document.querySelector('.levelList');
const categoryList = document.querySelector('.categoryList');
const timeList = document.querySelector('.timeList');

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(playButton).on('click', function() {
     if ($(levelList).children("li").hasClass('activeSelection') == false) {
       $(levelList).find('.warning').show();
     } else {
       startGame();
     } /** that's how I check one of the lists. I need to check all 3
      and if at least one does not have a class give a warning, but not 
      stop checking until all 3 lists are checked to give the rest of 
      the warnings if needed **/
  });

});
```

```css
.warning {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
      <div class="levelList">
        <h2>level</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>easy</li>
          <li>medium</li>
          <li>hard</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="warning">! please select level !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="categoryList">
        <h2> category</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>movies</li>
          <li>songs</li>
          <li>people</li>
          <li>animals</li>
          <li>random things</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="warning">! please select Category !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="timeList">
        <h2>time</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>1 min</li>
          <li>2 min</li>
          <li>3 min</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="warning">! please select time !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, your HTML is invalid. `ul` elements can only contain `li`, so the `h2` and `p` need to be moved outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing all 3 checks separately:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(playButton).on('click', function() {
     var status = 0;
     if ($(levelList).children("li").hasClass('activeSelection') == false) {
       $(levelList).find('.warning').show();
     } else {
        status += 1;
     } 
     if ($(categoryList).children("li").hasClass('activeSelection') == false) {
       $(categoryList).find('.warning').show();
     } else {
        status += 1;
     } 
     if ($(timeList).children("li").hasClass('activeSelection') == false) {
       $(timeList).find('.warning').show();
     } else {
        status += 1;
     } 
      if (status === 3)
       startGame();
  });
```